# Make the text as wide as the sibling image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Thats my codepen: http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/bEMoLa?editors=1100

I want that the text below the image does not go further than the right border of the image. Instead the text should line-break.

How can I do that?

```
<div style="background:orange;">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRmvFCHgvt3ywCj6yAxRKgnrU6VraZAIBtFSaP_maZInJ5GqmU1CQ" />Text below should stop at the image right border and line-break

  <h2>Sie haben Ihre Anfrage erfolgreich storniert!</h2>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>

</div>
```

**I do not want to hardcode the width of the image anywhere in my code.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the image and the text into a div like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <img src="#"/>
   <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit ammet</p>
</div>
```

Then give the wrapper the same width that the image, something close to this:

```
 .wrapper
{
  width: 350px
}
```

Thats one way, but you can also use a grid framework like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) to do this job

Comment: I use bootstrap3 how can I do that with BS3?

Comment: <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
 <img src="#"/>
  <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit ammet</p>
</div>
</div>

Set the image with width:100% to fill the full width of the col-md-, i used col-md-3 like a example, you can set this according to your image

Answer (score 0):

HTML Code:

```
<div class="mainDiv">
  <div class="pictureAndTexDiv">
    <div class="cell"> <img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/srpr/logo1w.png" /> <span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor.</span> </div>
  </div>
```

CSS for above:

```
.mainDiv {
    border: red 1px solid;
}
.pictureAndTexDiv {
    border: blue 1px solid;
    width: 1%;
    display: table;
}
.cell {
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Just change display to table

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the image and text together in a div and give it a width. Your image is 309px wide so make the div that dimension.

Comment: I do not want to hardcode the size obviously. Images change.

Comment: Then you should have stated this as a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this it is working:

```html
<html>
<style>
    .wrap {
        display: inline-block;
        position: fixed;
        background:orange;
    }

    .wrap img + div {
        position: absolute;
        margin: auto;
    }
</style>
<div class="wrap" >
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRmvFCHgvt3ywCj6yAxRKgnrU6VraZAIBtFSaP_maZInJ5GqmU1CQ" />
    <div class="wrap" >
        <h2>Sie haben Ihre Anfrage erfolgreich storniert!</h2>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>


</html>
```